# How to balance faster employee and their peers?

Tags: work-environment, work-life-balance, workload

I work in the Fintech/IT/Banking industry and understand the pressure of this field.

Recently, we had a product UI overhaul and everybody has to work over time.

What gets me is, I work faster than everybody else, and this turns out to be a wrong way to work. My supervisor just assigns me my peers tasks. I've seen my coworker slacking and avoiding working too fast and now I know why.

Is this okay and to be expected from any work field? I can sort of see the perspective where we need to help others as a "team".

**Is there a balance between giving incentives and helping others?**

Comment: So does your supervisor know that your colleagues are slacking off? When he/she sees you performing faster than your colleagues, what is their assessment?

Comment: @Kozaky no and no. my boss didn't know other's are slacking off. and my boss frequently delegate her work to "supervisor"s that did not care if somebody works better. this supervisor even suspect me of cheating for some reason, didn't hear my complaint that this is not fair, and doesn't really care who works how. this is not a one time thing.

Comment: Are you opposed to "slacking off" as well?  At my internship I complete the work much quicker than expected and as a result I need to find things to do, which has caused me to slow down a bit in response.

Comment: @TheRealLester well that's on thing i'm also asking. is okay to do this "strategic" slacking off? especially when our boss field of view is blurred by these supervisor.

Comment: Your boss won't think its OK, but as long as you are getting *your work and only your work* done in the time frame that is required for you then you won't really have a problem with management AFAIK.  No amount of reporting to the supervisor will cause your coworkers to work faster.

Comment: How can you be cheating at work assignments? If the quality of the work product is on-par with the expectation, it's not cheating. It's being smart and efficient. If you do repetitive work and you manage to automate it to reduce the time spent on it by orders of magnitude, that's not you cheating if the quality stays the same. That's you saving them money and becoming available for other tasks.

Comment: Sometimes, whenever I fee that I am faster than my peers, I follow this rule, whenever possible. Time given to complete the assignment = time within which I can complete the task + surplus time. In this surplus time, I can always help myself, or help my team members. Sometimes, this surplus time is zero, which is still okay, because I am not putting in more efforts. And never let anyone know that you have surplus time with you nor mention that you have completed your work way before the due date/time. Win-win situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One reality of the workplace is that some people are just faster, and good work is rewarded with more work.

Either you step back, or you negotiate for a lead position.  Also, **NEVER** give your full effort unless it is "crunch time".  It's a sad truth, but some employers simply assume that nobody is working at 100%.

How many times have you heard "Well, it's crunch time, so I need everybody to step it up a notch" or something similar.

If you don't step back, you will find yourself doing the work of six people.  That's fine if you're being paid for the work of six people, otherwise, no.

**TLDR**

You have several options.

1. Continue as you are, and risk burnout
2. Negotiate for more pay/promotion since you are doing more work
3. Step down your efforts
4. Continue to take on more responsibilities, update your resume and move on.

Comment: Probably a little late to step down efforts if his boss already has a set expectation.  He will get punished for slacking, even if he steps it down a little bit and is still working harder than his peers.  Trust me on this.  I suspect OP is a bit of a novice and has to learn this the hard way.

Comment: @solarflare You can slowly step down your efforts over a month or two, the boss probably wont notice.

Comment: Most bosses have no idea how to measure productivity anyways. I bet if you dropped to half speed he wouldn't even notice. If he notices then play dumb and ask about the metrics he's using (not answer his questions). Or credit the productivity to someone else helping you but now you're settled so you'll slow down a bit as you work on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Good on you for showing so much initiative and productivity.

If you're doing the lion's share of the work, that needs to be reflected in your salary.

The correct response to this is to go up to your boss and say "I seem to be doing a lot more work and creating a lot more value for the company than the other guys on my team. I think my pay packet ought to reflect that."

Answer (score 1):

**No, you should never "strategically slack off". They probably already know how strong of a worker you are and would consider this a drop in your performance.**

There needs to be a balance between you getting your work done, and helping the team get there's done as well.

If there is a imbalance enough to cause you this much anger or personal conflict, you need to sit down with your supervisor and managers to discuss the problem. I wouldn't throw any of your peers under the bus, because while you see them as slacking off, maybe there is other factors.

Make sure that you are recording all of the work that you are doing, and when it comes time to have a sit down meeting with management about your performance, use this number of tasks completed as a metric to suggest that you are out performing your peers (which can lead to quicker promotion, depending on the company).